# add multiple classes on ng-click in ng-repeat to a selected row

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to add some classes to the selected div in `ng-repeat`. If I do something like this:

```html
<div ng-class="{'selecte':isSelected,'normal':'!isSelected'}" ng-repeat="oneayah in ayahs" ng-click="selectParticular(oneayah)">
    {{oneayah.text}}
</div>
```

It changes the class of all divs within `ng-repeat`. (isSelect is a bool which toggles every time div is clicked.)

Comment: please ignore data.text, it is actually oneayah.text

Answer (score 1):

Your second `ngClass` param (`normal`) is checking the string `isSelected` since you quoted it, not the bool:

```
ng-class="{'selecte':isSelected,'normal':!isSelected}"
                                              ^^^REMOVE QUOTES AROUND ME
```